# Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithAndroidGradleClassShrinkerForDebug'

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, proguard, minify, shrinkresources

I am getting this error because I tried to reduce my apk size by referring this [document](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code/)

> Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithAndroidGradleClassShrinkerForDebug'.
>   Warnings found during shrinking, please use -dontwarn or -ignorewarnings to suppress them.

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            useProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

How to use `-dontwarn or -ignorewarnings to suppress them`? Where I have to add this key.

**Error stack-trace:**

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithAndroidGradleClassShrinkerForDebug'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Warnings found during shrinking, please use -dontwarn or -ignorewarnings to suppress them.
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.BuiltInShrinkerTransform.checkForWarnings(BuiltInShrinkerTransform.java:200)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.BuiltInShrinkerTransform.fullRun(BuiltInShrinkerTransform.java:178)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.BuiltInShrinkerTransform.transform(BuiltInShrinkerTransform.java:130)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:221)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:217)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:212)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
        ... 29 more
```

**Edit**

**proguard-rules.pro**

```
    # Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# You can control the set of applied configuration files using the
# proguardFiles setting in build.gradle.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-dontwarnclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}

# Uncomment this to preserve the line number information for
# debugging stack traces.
#-dontwarnattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

# If you dontwarn the line number information, uncomment this to
# hide the original source file name.
#-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile

-dontwarn <RoundedImageView>
-dontwarn <DOMSerializer>
-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-dontwarn java.nio.file.*
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn okhttp3.**
-dontwarn org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry
-dontwarn  com.androidquery.**
-dontwarn com.google.**
-dontwarn com.vimeo.networking.**
-dontwarn com.squareup.retrofit2.**
-dontwarn io.supercharge.**
-dontwarn com.github..**
-dontwarn com.android.**
-dontwarn com.airbnb.**
-dontwarn org.**
-dontwarn <google-services.json>
```

Now getting following error, If I remove `shrinkResources true` from build.gradle then won't get any error. But I need to reduce the apk file size using shrinkResources, How to resolve following error.

```
16:29:34.995 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Removing unused resources requires unused code shrinking to be turned on. See http://d.android.com/r/tools/shrink-resources.html for more information.
16:29:34.995 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.build.gradle.internal.errors.SyncIssueHandlerImpl.reportIssue(SyncIssueHandlerImpl.kt:53)
16:29:34.996 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueReporter$DefaultImpls.reportError(EvalIssueReporter.kt:137)
16:29:34.996 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.build.gradle.internal.errors.SyncIssueHandler$DefaultImpls.reportError(SyncIssueHandler.kt)
16:29:34.996 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.build.gradle.internal.errors.SyncIssueHandlerImpl.reportError(SyncIssueHandlerImpl.kt:30)
16:29:34.996 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.VariantScopeImpl.useResourceShrinker(VariantScopeImpl.java:457)
16:29:34.996 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.build.gradle.internal.TaskManager.createMergeResourcesTask(TaskManager.java:924)
16:29:35.003 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.build.gradle.internal.TaskManager.createAndroidTestVariantTasks(TaskManager.java:1907)
16:29:35.003 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.createTasksForVariantData(VariantManager.java:521)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the following configuration

```
debug {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        useProguard false
        ...
    }
```

you try to shrink the resources having `ProGuard` disabled. And since resource shrinking [works only in conjunction with ProGuard](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#shrink-resources) you get

```
Removing unused resources requires unused code shrinking to be turned on.
```

The following configuration should remove the build error:

```
debug {
    minifyEnabled true
    shrinkResources true
    ...
}
```

If after that you get `Warnings found during shrinking, please use -dontwarn or -ignorewarnings to suppress them` you gonna need to edit `proguard-android.txt` adding the corresponding `-dontwarn <package_name_with_wildcard_or_class_name>`.

Comment: Thank you for answer and it is fixed now and also I added `-dontnote` for some packages and classes which throwing some error notes.